# Use of select gives syntax error

Tags: bash, select, syntax, syntax-error

I am trying to get this to work:

```
echo "Would you like to configure dns?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
        Yes ) echo "you have selected to configure dns"; break;;
        No ) exit; break;;
    esac
done
```

I keep getting this error:

> menu.sh: 2: select: not found
>   menu.sh: 7: Syntax error: "done" unexpected

Thanks in Advance,
joe

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure you are running it in `bash` as `select` is understood by `bash` and not by some shells like `sh`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, just rewrite using `while`, `read` and `case`. I think `select` does not really add much.

Comment: Can you please giver me an example of how I could do it that way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good one I wrote up with the help from this Forum :)

```
     #!/bin/bash

        while ["$yn" != "Yes" ]; do

    echo "Choose your type of installation"

    echo "1) Home Media Server"

    echo "2) Home Communication Server"

    echo "3) Enterprise Communication Server"

    echo "4) Hosting Server"

    echo "5) Individual Packages"

    echo "6) exit"

    read case;



    #simple case bash structure

    # note in this case $case is variable and does not have to

    # be named case this is just an example



    case $case in

        1) echo "You have entered Home Media Server, is this correct? (Yes or No)"

      read yn

                echo "Running script for Home Media Server";;



        2) echo "You have entered Home Communication Server, is this correct? (Yes or No)"

      read yn

                echo "Running script for Home Communication Server";;



        3) echo "You have entered Enterprise Communication Server, is this correct? (Yes or No)"

      read yn

                echo "Running script for Enterprise Communication Server";;



        4) echo "You have entered Hosting Server, is this correct? (Yes or No)"

      read yn

                echo "Running script for Hosting Server";;



        5) echo "You have entered $hname, is this correct? (Yes or No)"

      read yn

                echo "Running script for Individual Packages";;



        6) exit

    esac
```